# PhantomJS scraping : Get CDATA in script tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom, phantomjs

I am trying to extract some JS generated data from a webpage, using PhantomJS.
I am able to get the page.content and I can see that the data I am interested in is enclosed within script and CDATA tags :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html style="" class="someclass">
    <head>
        <meta class="meta-class-1">
        <meta class="meta-class-1">

        <link rel="shortcut" type="image/x-icon" href="/assets/...">
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/page.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
        <script>
            //<![CDATA[
            window.gon={};gon.data={ "Interesting data":"the data" };
            //]]>
        </script>

        <script src="//anoterscript.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is one of my unsuccessful attempts at getting one of the scripts' content :

```
"use strict";
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('https://prioridata.com/apps/monzo-1052238659/country-split', function () {

  page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {

    var scriptCtnt = page.evaluate(function() {
       return [].map.call(document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].innerHTML, function(data) {             
            return data;
        });
    });

    console.log('Data is ' + JSON.stringify(data));

    phantom.exit()
  });
});
```

I've tried to parse the result in several different ways (libxml and node-phantom, page.content parsing using JQuery), but have been unable to get any script data so far. 
Is it possible to achieve this using PhantomJs ? What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: try using eval()...works in a browser http://plnkr.co/edit/fWihsSMC3ob1TzEhMlwE?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].innerHTML
> ```

First look at the tag you are selecting:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
> ```

It doesn't have any content. If you want to get the script, you need to make a new HTTP request to `https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js`.

It looks like you actually want this script:

> ```
>     <script>
>         //<![CDATA[
>         window.gon={};gon.data={ "Interesting data":"the data" };
>         //]]>
>     </script>
> ```

That **is not the first script on the page**. You need to select the right tag.

Possibly just by using `1` instead of `0`.

Comment: I've tried, but to no avail. The code I posted is over simplified, my script is at the 14th place or so.

Comment: Facepalm for me, you were right, I did a stupid mistake in the script ordering. Thanks for your help.